# tps61165 input capacitor

Tags: power-supply, power, led, driver

I'm considering using a tps61165 led driver for an LCD backlight. While I know it is far from recommended, I quickly breadboarded the typical application circuit using TH components that match the recommended SMD parts as much as possible, and used a SOT to DIP adapter for the IC.

In my case I have to go from 5V to 12.8V @ 40mA. (2x4 LEDs). For some reason the circuit works fine when I take out the C4 4.7uF input cap. When I do use it, I only get a really low output current, barely enough to light up the LEDs.

[image: led driver circuit]

Why could this be the case?

-- edit --

[image: the breadboard]

Notes:

- C4 is on the far right in this picture
  where I put it.
- R4 and R5 are not in this picture.
- R1 is 2x10R
- L1 is a Bourns RLB0712-100K
- D1 is an 1N5817

While I was editting the post to add the breakout picture, I noticed something new: When I enable power without C4 present, it will start up and light the LEDs at the desired power. Then I can add C4 while it is running and it will keep running and light the LEDs even brighter. But when I power up the circuit with C4 already there, it will get stuck in a low power output.

The location of adding C4 (after the circuit is running) also seems to matter. When I put it far away from the IC, it will increase brightness, but when I add it close to the IC when the system runs, it will shut down the cicruit.

Also when I power up the circuit with C4 present, I will get a weak constant output current when C4 is far away from the IC, but I'll only get a short blink once when I put it as close to the IC as the breadboard permits.

Comment: Could you post a picture of your breadboarded prototype?  Componet placement / wire length issues could perhaps be deduced from it.

Comment: picture and "BOM" added as well as an important new condition.

Comment: Did you try it with C4 directly across pins 1 to 4 of the chip?

Comment: yes see the additonal notes I just made to the post.

Comment: Just for interests sake, you could try adding a capacitor close to the chip when it is working with the far away capacitor and see what happens.

Comment: then it continues to work.

Comment: How about if you then pull the far away one?

Comment: You also might try minimizing the D1/C5 loop by grounding C5 directly on pin 4 of the chip.  You can make the D1/C5 connection in the row adjacent to the chip.

Comment: When i pull away the far one, it continues to work. Will test the loop thing tomorrow.

Comment: @crj11 if you want to collect some credit, please post your comment about tightening the D1/C5 loop as an answer and I will accept it :).

Comment: Glad you got it working!  I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to [minimize the area of the input and output current loops](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279232).  The the D1/C5 loop can be reduced by grounding C5 directly on pin 4 of the chip.  You can make the D1/C5 connection in the row adjacent to the chip.